# Getting an error as var5 is undefined ? but it runs fine without class

Tags: python, tkinter

```
class roger:
    root1 = Tk()
    frame1 = Frame(root1, width=100, height=100)
    frame1.pack(side=TOP)
    label5 = Label(frame1, text="x1=")
    label6 = Label(frame1, text="x2=")
    label7 = Label(frame1, text="x3=")
    label8 = Label(frame1, text="x4=")
    label5.grid(row=0)
    label6.grid(row=1)
    label7.grid(row=2)
    label8.grid(row=3)
    var5 = StringVar()
    var6 = StringVar()
    var7 = StringVar()
    var8 = StringVar()


    textbox1 = Entry(frame1, textvariable=var5, bd=10, width=10, font=30)
    textbox1.grid(row=0, column=1)

    textbox2 = Entry(frame1, textvariable=var6, bd=10, width=10, font=30)
    textbox2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    textbox3 = Entry(frame1, textvariable=var7, bd=10, width=10, font=30)
    textbox3.grid(row=2, column=1)

    textbox4 = Entry(frame1, textvariable=var8, bd=10, width=10, font=30)
    textbox4.grid(row=3, column=1)
    hoo = Entry(frame1, width=20, bd=10)
    hoo.grid(row=5, column=0)

    def inverse():
        a = ([float(var5.get()), float(var6.get())], [float(var7.get()), float(var8.get())])
        ans = inv(a)
        hoo.insert(0, ans)

    def eigen():
        a = ([float(var5.get()), float(var6.get())], [float(var7.get()), float(var8.get())])
        ans = eig(a)
        hoo.insert(0, ans)

    k = Button(frame1, text="inverse", command=inverse)
    k.grid(row=4, column=0)

    l = Button(frame1, text="eigen value ", command=eigen)
    l.grid(row=4, column=1)

    root1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code has multiple basic errors and I think it'd be beneficial for you to first [read on classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) from the official tutorial.

Comment: You appear to have just intented a block of code and stuck `class roger:` at the top - that's not how classes work. You need to move imperative codes into methods, and then actually have something call them. Also, the error is because you need to explicitly scope class or instance variables. Seriously, look at Ilja's link.

Answer (score 0):

Use `roger.var5` instead of `var5`, since you have defined it as class's static property. Similarly do for other variables.

Comment: I believe the preferred nomenclature in Python is simply *class attribute*, as distinguished from an instance attribute.

Comment: `roger` is the name of his class. OP has defined `var5` as `class property`, instead of `instance` property. In order to access it, syntax should be `<class_name>.<variable>`.

Comment: I simply meant that normally the descriptor *static* is dropped used in Python.